# Why removing create-react-app files and folders take a long while?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

When I want to remove **create-react-app** files and folders take a long while?
It is not using much of space, like 250MB.
Also I have to say my computer removes quickly another files and folders with size of bigger than create-react-app.

I use shift + Delete.

Comment: Kind of a irrelevant question, definitely doesn't pertain to the main StackOverflow board. But, React (and thus create-react-app) has a lot of *little* dependencies. Each with a lot of files. So, even though there isn't much space being used, it's lots of individual small files that all need to be removed. You can 'observe' this in pretty much any project using NPM/Yarn

Comment: @nbokmans
Okay and tnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React (and thus create-react-app) has a lot of little dependencies. Each with a lot of files. So, even though there isn't much space being used, it's lots of individual small files that all need to be removed. You can 'observe' this in pretty much any project using NPM/Yarn.